# How to add points by clicking on a graph in Dash?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly-dash

I am using the `clickData` event in Dash with the objective to create points on a scatter plot. But it looks like clickData only triggers if I click on existing points. I also tried with `relayout` instead of `ClickData`.
Is it possible to use something similar to add new points ?

Here is my code. It displays an empty graph and table:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='scatter-plot',
        figure={
            'data': [],
            'layout': {
                'clickmode': 'event+select',
            }
        }
    ),
    html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='datatable',
            columns=[
                {'name': 'X', 'id': 'x'},
                {'name': 'Y', 'id': 'y'}
            ],
            editable=True,
            row_deletable=True
        )
    ])
])

# Initialize an empty DataFrame to store the data
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['x', 'y'])

@app.callback(
    [Output('scatter-plot', 'figure'),
     Output('datatable', 'data')],
    [Input('scatter-plot', 'clickData'),
     Input('datatable', 'data_previous')],
    [State('datatable', 'data')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_graph_and_table(clickData, previous_data, current_data):
    global df

    if clickData:
        point = clickData['points'][0]
        new_point = {'x': point['x'], 'y': point['y']}
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame([new_point])], ignore_index=True)

    # Handle cell edits in the DataTable
    if previous_data:
        edited_row = [item for item in current_data if item not in previous_data]
        if edited_row:
            edited_row = edited_row[0]
            index = df[(df['x'] == edited_row['x']) & (df['y'] == edited_row['y'])].index[0]
            df.at[index, 'x'] = edited_row['x']
            df.at[index, 'y'] = edited_row['y']

    # Update the DataTable
    data_table = df.to_dict('records')

    # Update the Scatter plot
    scatter_figure = {
        'data': [
            {'x': df['x'], 'y': df['y'], 'type': 'scatter', 'mode': 'markers'}
        ],
        'layout': {
            'clickmode': 'event+select',
        }
    }

    return scatter_figure, data_table

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```